# C# Generics with 'Wildcards'

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.5

I'm looking for a way to get wildcards to work in `.NET` generics.

My code is as follows:

```
private class Rule<TSource, TSelected> where TSource : class where TSelected : class
{
    // stuff in here
}
```

I want to be able to create a List`<>` of Rules where the `TSource` will be the same but the `TSelected` may be different.

Comment: Where the TSource will be the same as what? Can you be more precise? What goes inside the `List<>`?

Comment: The answer might be possible, depending on the "stuff in here" part. Specifically, seeing all method signatures would be important.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a [contravariant generic interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx) `IRule<TSource, in TSelected>` and make a list of that, where in addition `TSelected` is going to be constrained to some meaningful class. Constraining to any reference type as in your existing code will compile, but you won't be able to do anything meaningful with anything that has to do with `TSelected`.

At this time there is no other way to use variant generics (unless of course you go into reflection mode with `List<dynamic>` or something equivalent), so if this solution does not work for you you will need to redesign.

Comment: It's rather unlikely that `TSelected` could be decorated with `in`: the `Rule` needs to return something, and `TSource` does not look like a suitable candidate (at least judging by its name).

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question right, I think you'd have to do this:

```
public interface ISelected
{
    // ISelected interface
}

// A TSelected implementation
public class Implementation1: ISelected { }
// Another
public class Implementation2 : ISelected { }

// our Rule
private class Rule<TSource, TSelected> where TSource : class where TSelected ISelected
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `TSelected` classes has the same super-class, you can just make a list of `Rule<TSource, TSelectedSuperClass>`. I believe you can use typeof (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs(v=vs.71).aspx) to get the exact subclass after reading the `TSelected` object again.

Alternatively you can make a container class to contain both and also store the exact types.

An interface could do it instead of a super class.  If the Selected share implementation however, I prefer an abstract class.

Comment: I do however agree on other comments that it is not clear what exactly you are trying to do with these rules.